# What locales are supported in Facebook Messenger Platform?

Tags: locale, bots, facebook-messenger

I was wondering what locales are actually supported in Messenger Platform.

I'm currently developing an Airline bot and I would like set up the locale depending on the user location.

I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a Facebook bot that uses locales and it seems they are the same supported by the Facebook API in general. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization

https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Comment: Great, I was going to respond myself with this same answer :) thnx!

Answer (score 0):

The new messenger profile API allows you to add localization to the persistent menu and greeting text

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/